# LAVA OTG adapter keeps android tablet from sleeping

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, standby, sleep

I am using an [EasyCAP Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LVTUX7E) via a [LAVA SimulCharge adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MOQFUQM) on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 to capture video from a car reverse camera.

This is working fine except, when the LAVA adapter loses the power from the car (when the car is turned off). the EasyCAP adapter's green light keeps blinking, (usually it's solid green when connected) and the 'USB adapter connected' notification appears and disappears continuously in notification bar, and the tablet refuses to go into sleep mode for about 4 minutes. (Pressing the power button makes the screen turn off and back on again immediately)

After 4 minutes, the EasyCAP light stops flashing and turns off, which lets the device go to sleep. The notification keeps firing, until the device is rebooted.

I think this is due to EasyCAP adapter trying to connect again which wakes up the device?

Is there a way to force the device to go to sleep?

Connecting the EasyCAP over a standard OTG cable works fine, but I need the tablet to charge simultaneously as well.

(switching the 'stay awake' option on and off in Developer Mode didn't help)

**UPDATE**

I noticed that if I set the lock-screen type to anything other than none (eg: swipe) and press the power button after power is disconnected, the adapter stops blinking and the device goes to sleep after screen timeout.

**UPDATE 2**

I have isolated the issue to the LAVA SimulCharge adapter. It seems like losing power at the other end causes this.. although disconnecting the wire for power at the adapter's end works fine. Would there be a physical sensor to detect if there's power?

Comment: If you phone support Qi (wireless) charging use it for charging the phone and use a standard (non charging) OTG adapter. Will that solve?

Comment: it would.. but Galaxy Tab S2 (or most tablets for that matter) doesn't have Qi charging.

Comment: I am also *about to* run into this problem. I am planning to mitigate it by using a 12v DC powered hub where I connect the EasyCap on to one of the USB ports and connect the USB hub's male cable to a OTG cable. I haven't tried this but I guess this should allow me to charge my phone and use OTG devices as well.  If this does not work I plan to fall back to Qi charger. For your phone there are Qi converters available, that makes any phone as Qi compatible.  See [this link](http://pocketnow.com/2014/12/31/how-to-retrofit-your-smartphone-or-tablet-with-qi-wireless-charging-video)

Comment: yea, I looked into Qi converters.. But they take up the USB port which prevents me from connecting the OTG cable/adapter. May be a normal OTG might work, but many people say droids don't support charging simultaneously most of the time. Let me know if you get a chance to try it.

Answer (score 0):

The LAVA SimulCharge has a chip in it that detects if charge power is being supplied.  If no charge power is being supplied it turns into a regular OTG connection.  When it does this, it draws power from the tablet to power your accessories.

From what I've looked at so far, I haven't found a way to make the OTG 5V power from the tablet turn off when the tablet goes into sleep mode. When the tablet goes to sleep, it seems to still be providing the OTG power.

My tablet will go to sleep, but drains the battery from the OTG connection.